# .htaccess RewriteRule not overriding URL

Tags: .htaccess, shared-hosting

I have this .htaccess which basically is supposed to turn my links from

```
http://www.dsbigiena.ro/products.php?product-id=Colac-wc-cu-folie-de-plastic-cu-actionare-manuala-prin-buton
```

to

```
http://www.dsbigiena.ro/Colac-wc-cu-folie-de-plastic-cu-actionare-manuala-prin-buton/
```

Unfortunately, it's not doing it.

Did I write it wrong?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /products.php?product-id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

EDIT: I did indeed test the .htaccess with "deny from all", and it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current rewrite rule only resolve a pretty URL. It won't convert an actual `/products.php` URL to the pretty one by itself. You need to have an explicit rule for that as

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirects from a normal URL to a pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /products\.php\?product-id=([^\ ]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [L,R=301]

# Resolves the pretty URL
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /products.php?product-id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Interestingly, it breaks everything and appends the parameter as a suffix: `http://www.dsbigiena.ro/Colac-wc-cu-folie-de-plastic-cu-actionare-manuala-prin-buton/?product-id=Colac-wc-cu-folie-de-plastic-cu-actionare-manuala-prin-buton`

Comment: Alex, you just need to add `?` to the first `RewriteRule`. This will strip the extra query string in the pretty url.